# Need to filter a column in GANTT view calendar

Tags: sharepoint-calendar

[image]

i want to filter the category column as marked in screenshot in my gantt view calendar.like only 'Freeze' or 'Release

Answer (score -1):

Edit view and add Filter

```
"Category" equal to "Freeze"
Or
"Category" equal to "Releases"
```

Comment: i want this from user to select.